# How can I link to awesomium using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, awesomium, clion

I'm new to developing using awesomium and I'm trying to get the helo world example running within Ubuntu. I'm using CLion which is using CMake as a build system. I was wondering how to link to Awesomium successfully using CMake.

Comment: Marched your way through this yet? http://www.awesomium.com/support/

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you, will check now,

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a long wave of trial and error:

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(LetsChat)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

find_package (Awesomium REQUIRED)
include_directories (${AWESOMIUM_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(LetsChat ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(LetsChat ${AWESOMIUM_LIBRARY})
```

FindAwesomium.cmake (Under CMake subdirectory)

```
include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_path(AWESOMIUM_INCLUDE_DIR Awesomium/WebCore.h
        PATH_SUFFIXES include
        PATHS
        ${AWESOMIUM_ROOT}
        $ENV{AWESOMIUM_ROOT}
        ~/Library/Frameworks
        /Library/Frameworks
        /usr/local/
        /usr/
        /sw          # Fink
        /opt/local/  # DarwinPorts
        /opt/csw/    # Blastwave
        /opt/)

find_library(AWESOMIUM_LIBRARY
        NAMES libawesomium-1-7.so
        PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib build/lib
        PATHS
        ${AWESOMIUM_ROOT}
        $ENV{AWESOMIUM_ROOT}
        ~/Library/Frameworks
        /Library/Frameworks
        /usr/local/
        /usr/lib/
        /usr/
        /sw          # Fink
        /opt/local/  # DarwinPorts
        /opt/csw/    # Blastwave
        /opt/)

find_package_handle_standard_args (Awesomium DEFAULT_MSG AWESOMIUM_INCLUDE_DIR AWESOMIUM_LIBRARY)
mark_as_advanced (AWESOMIUM_INCLUDE_DIR AWESOMIUM_LIBRARY)

if (AWESOMIUM_FOUND)
    message (STATUS "Found Awesomium: ${AWESOMIUM_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif ()
```